# How to intercept http requests from browser with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, http, proxy

I want to write a program to monitor all requests sending from my computer. For example: When I enter https://google.com in browser, the request first go through my program, and I can manipulate the response. How can I do it with nodejs?

Comment: Did you have a look to https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy ?

Comment: If use node-http-proxy, I have to manually make all requests redirect to the proxy-server. It can not automatically monitor http requests from browser.  @Julien TASSIN